# Delete the attributes value

Tags: oracle10g

How to delete the attributes **value** of a table in oracle 10g using sql command?

Example of problem like: Delete the email_id of employee James.-> I tried this code

```
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE01 WHERE MAIL_ID= 'james@gmail.com'
```

but after run output showed me that entire row was deleted but I want only email id delete from particular row.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to update a row, use `UPDATE`:

```sql
UPDATE EMPLOYEE01
SET MAIL_ID = NULL
WHERE MAIL_ID = 'james@gmail.com'
```

Here, `SET MAIL_ID = NULL` will remove the value from `MAIL_ID` field for the record identified by the `WHERE` clause.